# DataTables CDN fallback expressions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables, cdn

What are the CDN fallback expressions for the DataTables script and its extensions?
https://cdn.datatables.net

For example ([source](http://geekswithblogs.net/cskardon/archive/2014/07/04/cdnfallbackexpression-for-jquery-jquery.ui-modernizr-and-bootstrap.aspx)):

```
jQuery     -->  window.jQuery
jQuery.UI  -->  window.jQuery.ui
Modernizr  -->  window.Modernizr
Bootstrap  -->  $.fn.modal
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can determine whether jQuery DataTables is available by testing whether  `$.fn.dataTable` exists.

So I assume you need to use:

```
bundle.CdnFallbackExpression = "$.fn.dataTable";
```

Comment: What about the extensions? I am particularly interested in `Responsive` and `Scroller`.

Comment: @JulianLettner, look into their [code](http://datatables.net): `Responsive` is defined with `$.fn.dataTable.Responsive`, `Scroller` is defined with `$.fn.dataTable.Scroller`

Comment: in core you will need asp-fallback-test="jQuery.fn.dataTable"