# CDN fallback for DataTables.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, cdn, fallback

I am trying to write a CDN fallback for `datatables.min.js` -- somehow, I couldn't find any on Google or on datatables.net. After reading this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707750/datatables-cdn-fallback-expressions) and this [DataTables post](https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/23924/cdn-with-fallback), I came up with this *unsuccessful* piece (even tried various expressions as shown):

```
<script>
    if (typeof jQuery.fn.dataTable === 'undefined') {
        document.write('<script src="~/scripts/datatables.min.js"><\/script>');            
        //document.write('<script src="~/scripts/datatables.min.js">\x3C/script>'); //same
        //document.write('\x3Cscript src="~/scripts/datatables.min.js"\x3E\x3C/script\x3E'); //same
    }
</script>
```

For troubleshooting, I loaded `datatables.min.js` directly and got these two confusing results:

1/ I get `undefined` (BAD) from this:

```
<script>
    document.write('<script src="~/scripts/datatables.min.js"><\/script>');
</script>
<script>
    alert(typeof jQuery.fn.dataTable);
</script>
```

2/ ... but somehow I get `function` (GOOD) from that:

```
<script src="~/scripts/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script>
    alert(typeof jQuery.fn.dataTable);
</script>
```

That looks the same to me, especially since `document.write` uses synchronous loading. I also tried a pure DOM method but no luck.

**What am I missing with `document.write`?**

Comment: You are inserting `script` inside `script` in `<script>
    document.write('<script src="~/scripts/datatables.min.js"><\/script>');
</script>`

Comment: use `$.getScript('~/scripts/datatables.min.js?' + Math.random(), function () {
        
});` to load script dynamically.

Comment: The `document.write` method has been commonly used and recommended - e.g. see CDN fallback for jQuery (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257923/how-to-load-local-script-files-as-fallback-in-cases-where-cdn-are-blocked-unavai). I don't think it is the problem.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi - I tried $.getScript but it does not work either. It even returns a new `404 Not Found` error.

Comment: Yes you are write but it loads lately. so do stuff after it completely write to `DOM`

Comment: May be problem with `"~/scripts/datatables.min.js"` path. It can't find it and getting `404`. Can you please verify path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correct CDN fallback for DataTables following accepted fallback practices is:

```
<script>
    if (typeof jQuery.fn.dataTable === 'undefined') {
        document.write('\x3Cscript src="/scripts/datatables.min.js"\x3E\x3C/script\x3E');
        //document.write('<script src="/scripts/datatables.min.js"><\/script>');
    }
</script>
```

or simply

```
<script>window.jQuery.fn.dataTable || document.write('\x3Cscript src="/scripts/datatables.min.js"\x3E\x3C/script\x3E')</script>
```

The tilda / relative path in `src=""` was the problem, as suggested by @ParthTrivedi (see comments). Per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188218/relative-paths-in-javascript-in-an-external-file), "**when in script, paths are relative to displayed page**".

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    <script>
    if (typeof jQuery.fn.dataTable === 'undefined') {
        $.getScript(baseURL + '/scripts/datatables.min.js?' + Math.random(), function () {
            //do stuff here
            alert(typeof jQuery.fn.dataTable);
        });
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: This does not work and returns a `404 Not Found` error followed by `undefined`.

Comment: I have change URL. Please check. Try to give full Url Path. May be problem with relative url `"~/"`.

Comment: Nice catch! Per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188218/relative-paths-in-javascript-in-an-external-file, "When in script, paths are relative to displayed page..." Tilda / relative URL does not work in script. Your solution works but with a delay compared to the corrected `document.write` technique.

Comment: @Alfred is this answer help full to you? then do vote.

Answer (score 1):

In your code document.write and alert will process at the very same time, please realize that the alert will be done by the time "database.min.js" will be available.

Use $(document).ready() or winidow.onload and you will see expected results.

Though read the best practices, pros and cons here before doing this -

http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2012/04/10/dont-docwrite-scripts/

I will recommend using RequireJS to do this efficiently as described by Scott Hanselman, please go through the below link before attempting to it as he talks about CDN fallback in detail and has covered every aspect of it -

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CDNsFailButYourScriptsDontHaveToFallbackFromCDNToLocalJQuery.aspx

Hope it will help and will give you solid base to find correct directions.

Comment: I disagree when you say that `document.write` and `alert()` process at the same time. `document.write` is synchronous loading and executes outside of the script. Following that, `alert()` is processed, therefore after `document.write` has been executed. Therefore, `$(document).ready()` is not the way to go for loading a plugin since it will be missing while loading the page and generate errors. `document.write` is an accepted and recommended method for CDN fallbacks - see references above.

Comment: Agree, Scott Hanselman has it the way you needed as outlined in his post in my answers above.

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}
</script>

Though you may like his post for alternatives and other for performance perspective.